# missing dependency for method at parameter at index 0

Tags: java, rest

I am fairly new to REST services. I am trying to write a REST API method, which will take a List of objects and return some other list of objects.

something like :

```
**@POST
    @Path("/nodeinfo/{users}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<NodeLabels> getLocalizedLabels(
            @PathParam("users") Users users)
            throws WebApplicationException {**
            return new ArrayList(nodeLabelsIDMap.values());
    }
```

Users is just a list of another object user with attributes like `name`, `id`, `contact`, `country`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Rest, I suggest you should go over this quick tutorial first.

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/